# RTCPeerConnection not listening for track event of remote

Tags: javascript, angular, webrtc

I am trying to use WebRTC to implement video calling in an application. Connection is being established successfully between peers after sharing the offer, answer and ice-candidate.

Remote peer is sending the track (video, audio), but local peer (receiving peer) is not listing for the track of remote peer connection.

**Adding track to the peer connection :**

```
const localStream = await window.navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true, audio: true});
localStream.getTracks().forEach(track => {
    this.peerConnection.addTrack(track, localStream);
});
```

**Listening track event on other side :**

```
this.peerConnection.addEventListener('track', async (event) => {
          console.log("Remote video stream added to the video element...");
            remoteStream.addTrack(event.track);
        });
```

1. How to receive and show the video of remote peer?
2. Is there any way to inspect the stream/tracks of RTCPeerConnection?

We are using angular for our application. Here is the complete JS code :

1. Triggering video call component to offer call

```
  makeVideoCall(){
    var videoCallDialog = this.matDialog.open(VideoCallComponent, { 
      height: '600px', 
      width: '700px', 
      data : { 
        'friendUser' : this.friendUser
      }
    });
  }
```

2. Listening video call offer and trigger video-call component

```
    if (chatMessage.type == ChatType.VIDEO_CALL_OFFER){
      this.userChatService.findFriend(chatMessage.textFrom).subscribe(user=>{
        chatMessage.data = JSON.parse(chatMessage.data);
        var videoCallDialog = this.matDialog.open(VideoCallComponent, { 
          height: '600px', 
          width: '700px', 
          data : { 
            'friendUser' : user,
            'videoCallOfferChat' : chatMessage
          }
        });    
      });
    }
```

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { User } from 'src/app/user/model/user';
import { RxStompService } from '@stomp/ng2-stompjs';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { LoginService } from 'src/app/login/service/login.service';
import { Chat } from 'src/app/chats/model/chat';
import { ChatType } from 'src/app/chats/model/chat-type';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
import { CryptoService } from 'src/app/crypto/service/crypto.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-video-call',
  templateUrl: './video-call.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./video-call.component.css']
})
export class VideoCallComponent implements OnInit {

  currentUser : User;
  friendUser : User;
  chatSubscription : Subscription;
  peerConnection : RTCPeerConnection;
  offer : Chat;
  answer : Chat;
  iceCandidate : Chat;
  generatedIceCandidateCount = 0;
  receivedIceCandidateCount = 0; 
  iceCandidates = new Array<any>(); 

  constructor(
    private loginService : LoginService,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any,
    private stompService : RxStompService,
    private cryptoService : CryptoService
  ) {
    this.currentUser = this.loginService.getCurrentUser();
    if(data.friendUser){
      this.friendUser = data.friendUser;
      const configuration = {'iceServers': [{'urls': 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'}]};
      this.peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration);

      this.startReceivingStreams();

      // Listen for local ICE candidates on the local RTCPeerConnection
      this.peerConnection.addEventListener('icecandidate', event => {
        if (event.candidate) {
          // console.log('ICE Candidate generated', event.candidate);
          console.log("Genrated Candidate ", ++this.generatedIceCandidateCount);
          this.iceCandidates.push(event.candidate);
          // this.sendToSocket(this.createChat(null, ChatType.ICE_CANDIDATE, {'iceCandidate' : event.candidate}));
        }else{
          console.log("Candidates in buffer : ", this.generatedIceCandidateCount); 
          this.iceCandidates.forEach((candidate) => {
            this.sendToSocket(this.createChat(null, ChatType.ICE_CANDIDATE, {'iceCandidate' : candidate}))
          });    
          if(this.iceCandidates.length>0)
            this.startTransmittingStreams();
        }
      });

      // Listen for connectionstatechange on the local RTCPeerConnection
      this.peerConnection.addEventListener('connectionstatechange', event => {
        if (this.peerConnection.connectionState === 'connected') {
            console.log("Connection done...");
          }
      });

    }
    this.startListeningVideoCalls();
    if (data.videoCallOfferChat){
      this.startReceivingStreams();
      this.answerVideoCall(data.videoCallOfferChat);
    }
    else{
      this.offerVideoCall();
    }

  }
  
  ngOnInit(): void {}

  async startTransmittingStreams(){
    const localStream = await window.navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true, audio: true});
    localStream.getTracks().forEach(async track => {
        console.log("Adding track...", track);
        await this.peerConnection.addTrack(track, localStream);
    });
  }

   startReceivingStreams(){
    console.log("Start receiving...");
    let remoteStream = new MediaStream();
    this.peerConnection.ontrack = event => {
      console.log("[addEventListener] Remote video stream added to the video element...", event);
      let remoteVideo : any = document.getElementById('friendUserVideoTrack');
      remoteVideo.srcObject = remoteStream;
      remoteStream.addTrack(event.track);
    }
  }

  private startListeningVideoCalls(){
    if(this.stompService.connected()){
      this.chatSubscription = this.stompService.watch('/text/'+this.currentUser.id).subscribe((data:any)=>{
        let chat = JSON.parse(data.body);
        if(chat.data)
          chat.data = JSON.parse(chat.data);
        if (chat.type == ChatType.VIDEO_CALL_ANSWER) {
          console.log('Video Call Answer ...', chat);
          if (chat.data.answer) {
            // Contains RTCConnection answer then connect
            console.log('Call accepted', chat.data.answer);
            this.videoCallAnswered(chat);
          }else{
            // Doesn't contains RTCConnection answer : call rejected by recipient
            console.log('Call rejected...');
          }
        }
        if(chat.type == ChatType.ICE_CANDIDATE){
          console.log('Chat with ICE Candidate ', chat);
          this.iceCandidateReceived(chat.data.iceCandidate);
        }
      });
    }
  }

  async offerVideoCall() {
    var options = { offerToReceiveVideo: true, offerToReceiveAudio: true };
    const offer = await this.peerConnection.createOffer(options);
    await this.peerConnection.setLocalDescription(offer);
    this.sendToSocket(this.createChat(null, ChatType.VIDEO_CALL_OFFER, {'offer' : offer}));
  }

  private async answerVideoCall(receivedChat : Chat){
    if (receivedChat.data.offer) {
      let remoteDescription = new RTCSessionDescription(receivedChat.data.offer);
      await this.peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(remoteDescription);
      var options = { offerToReceiveVideo: true, offerToReceiveAudio: true };
      const answer = await this.peerConnection.createAnswer(options);
      await this.peerConnection.setLocalDescription(answer);
      this.sendToSocket(this.createChat(receivedChat.id, ChatType.VIDEO_CALL_ANSWER, {'answer' : answer}));
    }
  }

  private async videoCallAnswered(chat : Chat){
    const remoteDesc = new RTCSessionDescription(chat.data.answer);
    await this.peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(remoteDesc);
  }

  private createChat(id : string, chatType : ChatType, data : any){
    let chat : Chat = new Chat();
    chat.id = uuidv4();
    chat.textFrom = this.currentUser.id;
    chat.textTo = this.friendUser.id;
    chat.textFromName = this.currentUser.name;
    chat.textToName = this.friendUser.name;
    chat.date = new Date().getTime();
    chat.type = chatType;
    chat.message = this.cryptoService.encrypt(chat.message, this.friendUser.userChat.sk);
    chat.data = JSON.stringify(data);
    return chat;
  }

  private sendToSocket(chat : Chat){
    if(this.stompService.connected()){
      this.stompService.publish({
        destination : "/app/text/"+this.friendUser.id,
        body : JSON.stringify(chat)
      });  
    }
  }

  private async iceCandidateReceived(iceCandidate : any){
    if(this.peerConnection.remoteDescription){
      try {
        await this.peerConnection.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(iceCandidate));
        console.log("Received Count ", ++this.receivedIceCandidateCount); 
      } catch (e) {
          console.error('Error adding received ice candidate', e);
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Please try

```js
this.peerConnection.addEventListener('track',function(event){
remoteVideo=document.getElementById('remoteVideo'); //Change your remote 'video element' id here
remoteVideo.srcObject = event.streams[0];
});
```

2. Since WebRTC connections are peer to peer, we cannot inspect or monitor video from server. Only things signal servers will know are the SDPs and ice candidates shared via them.

Comment: I tried the changes suggested by you. But it is not entering into the callback of 'track' listener. 
`this.peerConnection.addEventListener('track', async (event) => {
          console.log("Remote video stream added to the video element...");
          let remoteVideo : any = document.getElementById('remoteVideo');
            remoteVideo.srcObject = event.streams[0];
           // remoteStream.addTrack(event.track);
        });` 
Not consoling the message on screen. I think it is not receiving any track from other peer, while other peer is transmitting the video and audio tracks.

Comment: Can you post your entire js here. So that we can try ourselves.

Comment: I have posted the complete code. Peers are getting connected, adding tracks to the connection successfully. But not listening 'track' event. Please help!

Comment: the problem is not the tracks but is the connection itself. Remember that the peers will start sending tracks only if the connection state is complete. Also try and clean the code a little bit and avoid calling events in different ways, it makes it hard to read :)

Answer (score 0):

I had to create the offer SDP differently.

```js
const offer = await peerConnection.createOffer({
    offerToReceiveAudio: true,
    offerToReceiveVideo: true,
});
```